# How to search for a datetimepicker value using textbox?

Tags: mysql, date, datagridview

I'm making a program with a search box and I want to use it to search for items based on its expiry date. I used a datetimepicker control to input the date into mysql database.

I placed the search box on a form with a datagridview and I want the search results to appear on it. This is the query I have so far.

`query = "select * from chemicalinventory where chemicalName like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' or expiryDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'"`

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it because there's a syntax error at `expiryDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'"` which is **end of statement expected**.

Please help!